# How can I select (or :not) a span of cells with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 7 cells and a bunch of rows.  I want to select all but the 1st, 5th and 6th.

I tried:

```
 $('table td:not(eq(5-6)):not(eq(1));
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
 $('table td:not(:eq(1)):not(:eq(5)):not(:eq(6))');
```

or:

```
 $('table td:not(:eq(1),:eq(5),:eq(6))');
```

Comment: I did this and it worked $('td:not(:eq(0),:eq(6),:eq(7))'); thanks

Comment: Also, specifically for spans, you can do this: `:gt(4):lt(7)` will give you effectively the non-existent `eq(5-6)`.